# Mongoose callback apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I updated to mongoose version  `4.10.5`  , but for some reason, now my aggregate is failing and getting the following error:

```
   \node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:214
            throw error;
            ^

TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
  at utils.promiseOrCallback.cb (C:\Users\Malin\Desktop\gameserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\aggregate.js:693:14)
    at Object.promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Malin\Desktop\gameserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:211:14)
    at Aggregate.exec (C:\Users\Malin\Desktop\gameserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\aggregate.js:690:16)
    at Function.aggregate (C:\Users\Malin\Desktop\gameserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2809:13)
```

What do i need to edit to make this work again?

The code that is beeing executed:

```
return Account.aggregate(
        // Limit to relevant documents and potentially take advantage of an index
        { $match: {
            haveusername: true,
        }},

        { $project: {
            total: { $add: ["$cash", "$bank"] }
        }}
    ).sort({total: -1}).limit(10).then(function (richest) {
//something else here

});
```

Comment: How about including the `sort` and `limit` as stages in the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Yeah, that could be something, but im not very good with aggregates atm.

Comment: Let me post an answer of how I would do it (but I not sure about the `then` chainning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `sort` and `limit` chaining methods, to stages in the aggregate call:

```
return Account.aggregate(
        // Limit to relevant documents and potentially take advantage of an index
        { $match: {
            haveusername: true,
        }},
        { $project: {
            total: { $add: ["$cash", "$bank"] }
        }},
        { $sort: {total: -1} },
        { $limit : 5 }
    ).then(function (richest) {
        //something else here
    });
```

Comment: MongooseError: Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators to `Model.aggregate()`. Instead of `Model.aggregate({ $match }, { $skip })`, do `Model.aggregate([{ $match }, { $skip }])`